# How to remove spaces after comma, in a column using SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I want to remove the space after comma, in a column using SQL script.
I am using oracle DB.

For example,
[image: DB structure]

I want a space (after sathish, kumar, raghavan) to be removed from column 'name',

I want the table to look like,[image: Required format]

likewise all the records to be modified.
I tried, this query,

```
update incitable SET name = LTRIM(RTRIM(name));
```

But it didnt make any chages,

Please help on this.

Sorry for the grammar mistakes.

Comment: Why are you storing lists of values in a single column? Assuming you're stuck with that data model, is it always exactly one space after the comma, or can there be several, or other whitespace like tabs?

Comment: No each comma separated value has a role to play in a single dropdown in the front end. The angular grid in my front end do not accept space or tab space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `replace()`:

```
UPDATE incitable
    SET name = REPLACE(name, ', ', ',');
```

`TRIM()` removes spaces at the beginning and end of the string, but not spaces in-between.  Given that `TRIM()` is available, there is no need to use `LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()` (unless you have a fetish for SQL Server).

Note:  Storing lists of values in a single column is a really, really bad idea.  Oracle offers many other solutions, such as a junction table (the SQLish way to store lists), nested tables, JSON formats, and no doubt more methods.

Comment: But will it work with values like "sss, safa, aafa, agag, agga"
which has more number of sub string.

Comment: @s.sathishkumar . . . It will work on any number of commas in the string.

Comment: @UdayShankar . . . That is not the question being asked here.  If you have another question, ask it as a *new* question.